# How to install a private npm github package during sls deploy

Tags: serverless-framework, github-actions

My CI/CD serverless deploy is failing because its not able to install a private npm package.

> Error --------------------------------------------------
>
> npm install failed with code 1
>     npm ERR! code ENOENT
>     npm ERR! syscall spawn git
>     npm ERR! path git
>     npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>     npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
>     npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/private-org/private-repo.git
>     npm ERR! enoent 
>     npm ERR! enoent 
>     npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
>     npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>     npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-05-28T13_30_18_595Z-debug.log
>
> ```
>   at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (/github/workspace/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/utils.js:91:16)
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
>   at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>   at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
> ```
>
> From previous event:
>         at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:505:22)
>         at PluginManager.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:525:17)
>         at ServerlessWebpack.BbPromise.bind.then.then.then (/github/workspace/node_modules/serverless-webpack/index.js:91:53)
>         at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>         at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>         at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>         at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
>
> Get Support --------------------------------------------
>        Docs:          docs.serverless.com
>        Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
>        Issues:        forum.serverless.com
>   Your Environment Information ---------------------------
>        Operating System:          linux
>        Node Version:              10.20.1
>        Framework Version:         1.54.0
>        Plugin Version:            3.6.12
>        SDK Version:               2.3.1
>        Components Core Version:   1.1.2
>        Components CLI Version:    1.4.0

```
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    needs: test
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'
    - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }} 
    - name: npm install
      run: npm install 
    - name: serverless deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        SLS_DEBUG: true
```

Usually i solve this using a webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0 so the first npm install works fine here and it manages to install the private package using the SSH key provided.

However during serverless deploy i get the above error and it cannot install the private npm package. Is there a way i can specify an SSH key for serverless action to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive come up with a solution but it meant i had to move away from the serverless action.

```
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    needs: test
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'
    - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: deploy
      run: |    
        npm i -g serverless
        npm install 
        serverless config credentials --provider aws --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        sls deploy
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same errors as you did and by mistake, I found the solution.
In circleCI, serverless was reading the ~/.npmrc file that was containing the authorization token for private npm packages, but it was not reading the local project .npmrc file that was containing the path for the private company packages.

So accidentally copy the private path to the ~/.npmrc and magically it the deployment t was successful.

After that I just update my circleCI step to get both pieces of information in the ~/.npmrc

```
step_login_github_packages: &step_login_github_packages
  name: Log in to Github Packages
  command: |
    echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$GITHUB_PACKAGES_TOKEN" >> ~/.npmrc
    echo "@my-company:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-company" >> ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: You are an angel!!! I was stuck with this problem for 2 days!